Azure DevOps YAML Pipelines - Scheduled Trigger Parameters
In Azure DevOps YAML pipelines, you can create scheduled triggers.  However, can each schedule have its own set of parameter values?  Such a thing could maybe look like this:
parameters:
- name: myParam
  displayName: My Parameter
  type: string
  default: option-a
  values:
  - option-a
  - option-b

schedules:
- cron: "0 5 * * *"
  displayName: "Midnight CT Daily"
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  parameters:
  - myParam: option-b
  always: true


Unfortunately, the YAML schema for the schedules.cron object does not have any properties that allow input of specific parameters.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/schedules?view=azure-pipelines
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/schedules-cron?view=azure-pipelines
However, I was able to get around this issue by leveraging the display name of the schedules.  From there, you can leverage PowerShell or Bash to read the $(Build.CronSchedule.DisplayName) variable and use that as input instead.  You could even delimit this value to parse out multiple values.
parameters:
- name: food
  type: string
  default: roast-beef
  values:
  - apple
  - banana
  - roast-beef
  - yogurt

schedules:
- cron: "0 5 * * *"
  displayName: "apple"
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  always: true
- cron: "0 7 * * *"
  displayName: "banana;yogurt"
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  always: true

stages:
- stage: mealtime
  jobs:
  - deployment: snack
    environment: kitchen
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - pwsh: |
              $targetFoods = @("${{ parameters.food }}")
              
              if ("$(Build.Reason)" -eq "Schedule") {
                $targetFoods = "$(Build.CronSchedule.DisplayName)".Split(";")
              }
              
              Write-Host "Foods to eat: $targetFoods"
              Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=foods;]$targetFoods"
            displayName: Set Variables

          - pwsh: |
              $(foods) | ForEach-Object { Write-Host "Eating: $_"; $_ | Eat-PsFood }
            displayName: Eat Food

